# adding total to bottom of multiindex groups

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to add a sum to my multiindex dataframe by each grouping

```
                          Count
state    car   status
texas    civic New           11
               undamaged     11
               damaged       10
               totalled       5
virginia civic New           10
               undamaged     20
               damaged       10
               totalled       5
```

I want it to look like:

```
                          Count
state    car   status
texas    civic New           11
               damaged       10
               totalled       5
               undamaged     11
               total         37
virginia civic New           10
               damaged       10
               totalled       5
               undamaged     20
               total         45
```

I have tried

```
s = test.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s.index, ['Total']])

df_out = df_full.append(s).sort_index()
```

but it throws

> NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex

Comment: Can you put the relevant code in a cod block please? Hard to distinguish between all of the text you put up.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: I don't know the solution off the top of my head but have you looked at `DataFrame.pivot()` and `DataFrame.pivot_table()` to see if they can do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` doesn't support product between multindex and list, instead you can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_frame`

```py
s = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(s.index.to_frame().assign(status='total'))
out = df.append(s).sort_index()
```

```
print(out)

                          Count
state    car   status
texas    civic New           11
               damaged       10
               total         37
               totalled       5
               undamaged     11
virginia civic New           10
               damaged       10
               total         45
               totalled       5
               undamaged     20
```

However, `.sort_index()` will change the index order, you can try following instead

```py
df_ = df['Count'].unstack()
df_['total'] = df_.sum(axis=1)
df_ = df_.stack().to_frame('Count')
# or in one line
df_ = (df['Count'].unstack()
       .pipe(lambda d: d.assign(total=d.sum(axis=1)))
       .stack().to_frame('Count'))
```

```
print(df_)

                          Count
state    car   status
texas    civic New           11
               damaged       10
               totalled       5
               undamaged     11
               total         37
virginia civic New           10
               damaged       10
               totalled       5
               undamaged     20
               total         45
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way I’ve implemented this in my workflow is to use the Sidetables package. [Link](https://github.com/chris1610/sidetable)

You can use it like: test.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().stb.subtotal(sub_level=2) will accomplish what you’re looking for.